# select from 2 tables with multiple counts

Tags: sql, join, count

I have 2 tables I'm trying to join in a select query.

**Table 1: Store, primary_key(id,store_num)**

```
store_id  store_num     due_date     manager_id
    1       100        06-30-2024      user1
    2       108        06-30-2018      user2
    3       109        13-31-2014      user3
```

**Table 2: Department, where status(A-applied,p-Pending)**

```
store_id  store_num     dept_num      status
    1       100           201           A
    1       100           202           A
    1       100           203           P
    1       100           204           A
    1       100           205           P
    1       100           206           A
```

Expecting to select store_id, store_num, due_date, manager_id, Applied count, pending count. The result is something looks like this.

```
store_id  store_num     due_date     manager_id  applied_count    pending_count
    1       100        06-30-2024      user1          4               2
```

I tried it and got where I am able to join and get it in multiple rows, But counts not working out for me. can some one help me how I can get the counts

```
select 
   store.store_id, 
   store.store_num, 
   store.due_date, 
   store.manager_id, 
   dept.status 
from store as store 
inner join department as dept on store.store_id = dept.store_id
                             and store.store_num = dept.store_num
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is half way done.  You need to do an aggregation to get the values in different columns.  This is a conditional aggregation, as shown here:

```
select s.store_id, s.store_num, s.due_date, s.manager_id,
       sum(case when d.status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Active_Count,
       sum(case when d.status = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as Pending_Count
from store s inner join
     department as dept
     on s.store_id = d.store_id and s.store_num = d.store_num
group by store.store_id, store.store_num, store.due_date, store.manager_id;
```

The expression:

```
       sum(case when d.status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Active_Count,
```

Is counting the rows where `status = 'A'`.  It does so by assigning such rows a value of `1` and then summing up that value.